# Plotting a Chart when Data isn't there

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot

I'm just trying to plot monthly data when there is no data for two months.  My code is below, where the data for Months April and May is empty.  However, when I try to plot the chart, I get an error

> Error: (converted from warning) Removed 2 rows containing non-finite values (stat_boxplot).

If I just add a zero in each entry (instead of NA) I get the plot, but now with a value when there shouldn't be any (see https://i.stack.imgur.com/CHI51.png). If I add na.omit(df) it just removes the two months.  Could someone assist me please?

```
Cost_Delta<-c(85000,-32672.62,28335.64,-85000,30963.5,-28335.64,NA,NA,
      -85000,32672.62,85000,-32672.62,-85000,-32672.62,85000,
      -32672.62,-85000,32672.62,85000,32672.62,-85000,-32672.62)
Month<-c("Jan","Jan","Feb","Feb","Mar","Mar","Apr","May","Jun","Jun",
     "Jul","Jul","Aug","Aug","Sep","Sep","Oct","Oct","Nov","Nov","Dec","Dec")
df<-data.frame(Cost_Delta,Month)
df$Month <- as.character(df$Month)
df$Month <- factor(df$Month, levels=unique(df$Month))
library(ggplot2)
p<-ggplot(df, aes(x=Month, y=Cost_Delta)) +
  geom_point(aes(fill=Month), size=2, shape=21, colour="grey20",
             position=position_jitter(width=0.2, height=0.1)) +
  geom_boxplot(outlier.colour=NA, fill=NA, colour="grey20") +
  scale_y_continuous(labels=scales::comma,breaks=seq(-300000,400000,50000)) +
  labs(x="Month-Year", y="Cost Delta (Demand-Mean Forecast)") 
p
```

Comment: Running your code I get `Error in check_breaks_labels(breaks, labels) : object 'comma' not found`

Comment: Jack, you need to install scales.  Just added in code.

Comment: Add `na.rm = TRUE` to both `geom`s, or use default settings where this is just a warning instead of an error.

Comment: (p.s. you can't use `library()` that way, and I had already fixed the issue.)

Comment: Perfect, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ggplot2` warns the user when they try to plot `NA` values. If you want to explicitly ignore this behavior, you can use the argument `na.rm = TRUE` with the layer.

```
Cost_Delta<-c(85000,-32672.62,28335.64,-85000,30963.5,-28335.64,NA,NA,
              -85000,32672.62,85000,-32672.62,-85000,-32672.62,85000,
              -32672.62,-85000,32672.62,85000,32672.62,-85000,-32672.62)

Month<-c("Jan","Jan","Feb","Feb","Mar","Mar","Apr","May","Jun","Jun",
         "Jul","Jul","Aug","Aug","Sep","Sep","Oct","Oct","Nov","Nov","Dec","Dec")


df <- data.frame(Cost_Delta, Month)
df$Month <- as.character(df$Month)
df$Month <- factor(df$Month, levels = unique(df$Month))


library(ggplot2)

p <- ggplot(df, aes(x = Month, y = Cost_Delta)) +
  geom_point(
    aes(fill = Month),
    size = 2,
    shape = 21,
    colour = "grey20",
    position = position_jitter(width = 0.2, height = 0.1),
    na.rm = TRUE
  ) +
  geom_boxplot(outlier.colour = NA,
               fill = NA,
               colour = "grey20", 
               na.rm = TRUE) +
  scale_y_continuous(label = scales::comma, breaks = seq(-300000, 400000, 50000)) +
  labs(x = "Month-Year", y = "Cost Delta (Demand-Mean Forecast)")

p
```

[image: example]